# How I add or hide a select tag from radio buttons yes and no?

Tags: jquery

I have a big Form with 10 labels with selects or inputs beside. At the end of this form I have two radio buttons inline(yes,no) and I want with the choice "no" to create below of this tenth label another new eleventh label (with select tag) and with the choice "yes" to hide this eleventh label from below (with the select tag).

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3"> Is that new? </label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="optradio"
            id="buy_no"/>No </label>
        <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="optradio"
            id="buy_yes"/>Yes </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" id="label_form"> Months</label>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <select class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Month"
        name="month_change" id="month_change">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

With choice No:

[image]

With choice Yes:

[image]

Comment: What jQuery have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Use **.is(':checked')** to see if a checkbox is Checked in jQuery.

```
if($('#buy_no').is(':checked')) { 
// Show the div you want to show.
}

if($('#buy_yes').is(':checked')) { 
// Hide the div you want to hide.
}
```

Remember to put this codes into **document.ready**

Answer (score 1):

Just show or hide it based on the `id` or `value` of the radio button selected like below on the `onchange` event

Add a class `month_change` to the div too and hide the div instead of the select box

```js
$(function(){
  $('.month_change').hide();
  $('input[name="optradio"]').on('change', function() {
      if($(this).attr('id') == 'buy_no') {
        $('.month_change').show();
      }else {
        $('.month_change').hide();
      }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3"> Is that new? </label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="optradio"
            id="buy_no"/>No </label>
        <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="optradio"
            id="buy_yes"/>Yes </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group month_change">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" id="label_form"> Months</label>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <select class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Month"
        name="month_change" id="month_change">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :). Could you accept this as an answer